# Azure Data Factory - tumbling window trigger will not start (stuck in the past)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have pipelines that I need to run in sequence. The first is a "raw to bronze," which runs daily at 4am. Once that completes, I want my "bronze to silver" to kick off. Raw to bronze is running just as expected (tumbling window every 24 hours), and it successfully completes. Bronze to silver is configured as a tumbling window trigger with dependency on raw to bronze, but its window is stuck in November 2021. I have tried combinations of offset and window size (0 offset to fire immediately, and a +4 hour window size to run in the next 4 hours), but the problem remains. I have also deleted and re-created the trigger. Still the dependency window is November 2021.

raw to bronze configuration:

[image: raw to bronze configuration]

bronze to silver configuration:

[image: bronze to silver]

And when I look at trigger runs, I see the window is stuck in the past:

[image]

Any ideas what I might be missing? All I am wanting is for the bronze to silver to kick off immediately after raw to bronze completes. Raw to bronze takes about an hour to run.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I repro’d in my lab, and it worked when I started the 2nd tumbling trigger (which is dependent on trigger 1) a minute before the dependency trigger (A_to_B).

**Tumbling trigger A_to_B:**

[image]

**Tumbling trigger B_to_C:**

1. Created this trigger to start 1 min earlier than the dependency trigger (A_to_B).
2. While creating it, it asks to re-align offset for dependency by the difference time as shown in the below snip.

[image]

[image]

**Trigger runs:**

> First B_to_C trigger starts with status as waiting on dependency. A minute later A_to_B trigger starts running and when completes it changes the status to succeed. Now B_to_C trigger starts running and completes successfully.

[image]